# How to return to starting point in a height profile - QGIS 3.32.0-Lima

Tags: qgis, route, profile

I have two layers:

1. waypoints and
2. DEM

Currently, I have a graph that shows height from one point to another. However, I wish to return to my starting point at the end.

I have already tried to just insert a new point that has the same coordinates as the first one. Indeed, I could create lines between the points that led back to the starting point with the function "points to path". However, on the height profile, the return to the last additional point was not shown.

Interestingly, the DEM in the height profile continues to where the last point would have been, but no line or waypoint is shown. This is also the case, when I don't have an additional waypoint.

**How can I display the last point?**

*Description to reproduction*

1. Download DEM: https://gis.ktn.gv.at/OGD/Geographie_Planung/ogd-10m-at.zip
2. Load it into QGIS
3. Copy the waypoints into a file (attention to the tabs and brackets), import it to get the waypoints --> **use the settings of the picture below**
4. use the function "points to path" to make lines between the points
5. use the intern height profile tool (in category "View", named "Elevation Profile") of QGIS and select the line
6. find a solution that I didn't, to show the last waypoint in the profile

*The used coordinates:*

After the first line, there should be a tab between each value.
The last line in brackets would be the copied additional waypoint.
Don't care about the height being below the ground, this is expected.

```
QGC WPL 110
0   0   3   16  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000  47.75455960 15.55200580 0.000000    1
1   0   3   16  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000  47.75709860 15.56711200 200.000000  1
2   0   3   16  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000  47.75340550 15.58324810 200.000000  1
(3  0   3   16  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000  47.75455960 15.55200580 0.000000    1)
```

*Picture of settings:*
[image]

*Picture of height profile, the red dot is the wanted waypoint:*
[image]

Comment: My current solution is to change the last comma value of the copied last waypoint. Somehow, the tool doesn't seem to accept the last copied point, if it has the exact same location...